# Zend_Auth - Be Able To Login With Both Email And Username

Tags: zend-framework

So I am using Zend_Auth to authenticate users of my website. Currently they are only able to log in with their email as login but I would like to enable them to log in also with their username.

Here is some code:

```
        // prepare adapter for Zend_Auth
        $adapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($this->_getDb());
        $adapter->setTableName('users');
        $adapter->setIdentityColumn('email');
        $adapter->setCredentialColumn('password_hash');
        $adapter->setCredentialTreatment('CONCAT(SUBSTRING(password_hash, 1, 40), SHA1(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(password_hash, 1, 40), ?)))');
        $adapter->setIdentity($request->getParam('email'));
        $adapter->setCredential($request->getParam('password'));
```

Notice the line:

```
        $adapter->setIdentityColumn('email');
```

How can I add also username there (column in the database called username, too)?

UPDATE:

This is how I solved this:

```
        $login = $request->getParam('email');
        $validator = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();
        if (false === $validator->isValid($login)) {
            $u = $this->_getTable('Users')->getSingleWithUsername($login);
            if (null === $u) {
                throw new Exception ('Invalid login and/or password');
            }
            $login = $u->email;
        }

        // prepare adapter for Zend_Auth
        $adapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($this->_getDb());
        $adapter->setTableName('users');
        $adapter->setIdentityColumn('email');
        $adapter->setCredentialColumn('password_hash');
        $adapter->setCredentialTreatment('CONCAT(SUBSTRING(password_hash, 1, 40), SHA1(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(password_hash, 1, 40), ?)))');
        $adapter->setIdentity($login);
        $adapter->setCredential($request->getParam('password'));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I deal with the same thing, and I handle it before Zend_Auth.  I use a single user sign-in field and first check whether it's an email address -- if so, it's converted to the appropriate username.  Then, let Zend_Auth do its thing.

This works well for me, *although you'll need to kinda switch it around*, since you're going the other way.

*i.* Add a filter to your user sign-in field, like this:

```
$user_field->addFilter('EmailToUsername');
```

*ii.* The filter:

```
<?php

/**
 * Converts an email address to the username.
 */
class Prontiso_Filter_EmailToUsername implements Zend_Filter_Interface
{
  public function filter( $value )
  {
    if ( Zend_Validate::is($value, 'EmailAddress') ) {

      $user_table = new Users();
      $user = $user_table->findByEmail($value);
      if ( $user ) {
        return $user->username;
      }
    }

    /**
     * Nothing happened, so don't filter.
     */
    return $value;
  }
}
```

As for just changing a `Zend_Auth` setting instead, `Zend_Auth` doesn't like either/or identity columns, so you'd have to write your own auth adapter.

Comment: I have solved it by using the email adress validator in the controller instead in the form. Check out my updated post. I don't like creating custom filters and such and this works as well.

Answer (score 4):

My own solution:

```
$adapter->setIdentityColumn(stripos($indentity, '@') ? 'email' : 'username');
```

Fast and simple!

Comment: This is simple indeed, still there is a weakness when username could be email too, that is different than the email in the other column. Still there is very small chance this to happens.